# Как сделать условие для вывода полей Advanced Custom Fields в WordPress?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, cms, phpstorm

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать условие, чтобы вывод поля ACF делался только тогда, когда, оно заполнено. Потому что если в записе поле не заполнено и делается его вывод, то возвращает такой код:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
/home/matchpclub/matchpoint-club.com/docs/wp-
content/themes/matchpoint/restaurant-menu.php on line 13
```

Нужно написать условие чтобы ничего не выводилось если поле не заполнено.

В ACF я делал вывод повторителя:

```
<?php
echo '<ul id="dishes-list" class="dishes-list">';

$mainDish = get_field('main_dish');
foreach ($mainDish as $mainDishItem) {
    ?>
    <li class="dishe">
        <p class="dishe__name">
            <?= $mainDishItem['main_dish_name']?>
        </p>
        <p class="dishe__price">
            <?= $mainDishItem['main_dish_price']?>
        </p>
    </li>
    <?php
}

echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$main_dish_name = get_field('main_dish_name');
if( !empty($main_dish_name) ):
   echo $main_dish_name;
endif;
```